# Simulating a command queue and undo stack with RxJS

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm attempting to replicate [this demo](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Command_2.aspx) using RxJS. The demo is a small application, where the user controls a robot. The robot can move forwards or backwards, rotate left or right, and pick up or drop an item. The user can queue commands (such as "Forward", "rotate"), and the commands in the queue are executed when the user clicks on the "Execute"-button. The user can also undo *commands that have been already executed*.

Traditionally this application would be quite easy to implement using a queue for the commands that have not been executed yet. Executed commands are pushed into a stack, and whenever the undo-button is pressed, the top command is popped and undone.

I'm able to "collect" the commands and execute them by doing this:

```
var id = 0;
var add = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#add"), 'click').map(function(){
  var ret = "Command_"+id;
  id++;
  return ret
})
var invoke = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#invoke"), 'click')
var invokes = add.buffer(invoke)
```

The buffer() method transforms the stream into a stream of arrays. I can either subscribe to the invokes stream and get arrays of commands:

```
invokes.subscribe(function(command_array){...})
```

or I can create a Rx.Subject() where I just push the commands one by one:

```
var invoked_commands = new Rx.Subject()
invokes.subscribe(function(command_array){
  for(var i=0; i < command_array.length; i++){
    invoked_commands.onNext(command_array[i])
  }
});

invoked_commands.subscribe(function(command){ ...});
```

To be honest I have no idea which approach would be better, but I then again I don't know if that's even too relevant to me right now. I've been trying to figure out how to implement the undo functionality, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

In my mind it would have to be something like this (sorry for the formatting):

-c1---c2-c3--------->

----------------u---u-> ("u" = clicking the undo button)

----------------c3--c2> (get commands from newest to oldest, call the undo() method)

So my question is twofold:

1. Is my approach of collecting the commands good?
2. How can I implement the undo feature?

EDIT: I'm comparing transformative and reactive styles, and I'm implementing this demo using both. Therefore I'd like to stick to using Rx* features as much as possible.

Comment: There’s a [similar newer question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30006646/2816199) with a [very succint answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30011133/2816199) out there.

Comment: It turns out that the answer solves a slightly different problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go ahead and maintain state for the undo stack.  I think your approach to collecting commands is reasonable.  If you keep your `Subject` you can sort of decouple the undo functionality from the command execution by making another subscription to the subject:

```
var undoQueue = [];
invoked_commands.subscribe(function (c) { undoQueue.unshift(c); });
Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($("#undo"), "click")
    .map(function () { return undoQueue.pop(); })
    .filter(function (command) { return command !== undefined; })
    .subscribe(function (command) { /* undo command */ });
```

Edit: Using only Rx without a mutable array.  This seems unnecessarily convoluted, but oh well, it is functional.  We use `scan` to maintain the undo queue, and emit a tuple with the current queue along with whether a undo command should be executed.  We merge executed commands with undo events.  Execute commands add to the queue, undo events pop from the queue.

```
var undo = Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($("#undo"), "click")
    .map(function () { return "undo"; });
invoked_commands
    .merge(undo)
    .scan({ undoCommand: undefined, q: [] }, function (acc, value) {
        if (value === "undo") {
            return { undoCommand: acc.q[0], q: acc.q.slice(1) };
        }

        return { undoCommand: undefined, q: [value].concat(acc.q) };
     })
     .pluck("undoCommand")
     .filter(function (c) { return c !== undefined })
     .subscribe(function (undoCommand) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any way I could do this (almost) purely using Rx features? Meaning, I'd rather not use an array like that. I forgot to mention this, but this demo is for my master's thesis and I'm comparing how the application is implemented using a transformative style vs a reactive style; hence I kind of have to stick to streams even if it is inconvenient.

Comment: I added code to do it purely reactive.  Maybe there's a better way?  I can't think of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right it does look very convoluted, oh well. I'm not completely sure I understand all of it, but I'll test it tomorrow and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: It worked! Awesome. Some fixes though: the first return in scan() should have "q: ACC.q.slice(1)"; and to simulate a stack the second return should have "q: [value].concat(acc.q)". I'll mark your answer as accepted, but if you could fix these then I'm sure it'll be more helpful for others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I just created something similar, although a bit more complex.
Maybe it helps someone.

```
  // Observable for all keys
  const keypresses = Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(document, 'keydown')

  // Undo key combination was pressed
  //  mapped to function that undoes the last accumulation of pressed keys
  const undoPressed = keypresses
    .filter(event => event.metaKey && event.key === 'z')
    .map(() => (acc) => acc.slice(0, isEmpty(last(acc)) && -2 || -1).concat([[]]))

  // a 'simple' key was pressed
  const inputChars = keypresses
    .filter(event => !event.altKey && !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey)
    .map(get('key'))
    .filter(key => key.length === 1)

  // the user input, respecting undo
  const input = inputChars
    .map((char) => (acc) =>
      acc.slice(0, -1).concat(
        acc.slice(-1).pop().concat(char)
      )
    ) // map input keys to functions that append them to the current list
    .merge(undoPressed)
    .merge(
      inputChars
        .auditTime(1000)
        .map(() => (acc) => isEmpty(last(acc)) && acc || acc.concat([[]]))
    ) // creates functions, that start a new accumulator 1 sec after the first key of a stroke was pressed
    .scan(
      (acc, f) => f(acc),
      [[]],
    ) // applies the merged functions to a list of accumulator strings
    .map(join('')) // join string
    .distinctUntilChanged() // ignore audit event, because it doesn't affect the current string
```

Answer (score 0):

It's great to diy first. Reinventing the wheel comes with deeper understanding of concepts & makey you a brillant engineer, in real life sometimes you just gotta benefit from an already existing package to:

- save time (efficiency)
- ensure stability (community approved)
- less code (maintainability)
- generic package (reusability)

[rx-undoable](https://github.com/Widdershin/rx-undoable)

Update:

I'm more happy with Zundo now, also due to code review and usage of TypeScript and < 1kb (no offense to other lib, it works, so it's great too)

[Github: 'zundo'](https://github.com/charkour/zundo)

---